# Not Showing Slider Range in Slider bar react-native Android

Tags: react-native

I am Developing Sample Application, Actually I created Slider using react native Android.I have A small problem with slider,when i was set on particular Distance on Slider or move on slider it's not showing(Actually in this I was Given State value Default value is 5, but in Slider not move, Showing value Range fine, But not move an Slide bar)

Here this my Code:

```
state value is 5

import Slider from react-native

 <Slider
                        minimumValue={0}
                        maximumValue={50}
                        onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({value: parseInt(value)})}
                        step={1} />
                      <Text>{parseInt(this.state.value)} KM</Text>
```

Initially The Range Shows Five But not move the Slider:(Image Here)
[image]

But I want Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you haven't set value to slider.

do like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        switchValue: true,
        distance: 90,
      }
  }

<Slider
     style={styles.slider}
     value = {this.state.distance}
     minimumValue={0}
     maximumValue={100}
     step={1}
     onSlidingComplete={val => this.setState({ distance: val })} />

<Text style={styles.distance2}>{this.state.distance} Miles</Text>
```

this is the output:

[image]